# How to handle the verification of an account in an application process

Tags: process, verification

I'm redesigning an application process; the process has around 8 steps, each step varies in length.

At the beginning of the process, we ask the user to create an account by entering an email address and a password. The client doesn't want to make the user verify their account via email verification as he's concerned it will decrease completion of the application process. (User leaves the process to confirm their account, gets distracted and doesn't return).

There is a part of the process where the user must upload documents and the tech stakeholder is saying that it's a security risk to allow unverified accounts to upload documents.

Any advice on how to handle the situation? Thanks!

Comment: What industry is the application process in? Is there sensitive data? Why would you need to upload a document in the sign-up? Can you defer the upload until after account creation - and then run through the email verification process then?

Comment: Hi, it's for a Visa application. And the data is sensitive yes as it's personal.

Comment: Good point about perhaps uploading the documents later, I will give it some thought to see if that's even possible!

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense to ask for the email (and complete the verification process) at the end of the application process? Since they have spent time and effort to fill the form, they'll be more willing to verify their email.

You can trash their info if they don't verify within a certain time.